# issue while importing apollo-link-http using webpack

Tags: webpack-2, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am getting error while bundling files using webpack when I am trying to import 'apollo-link-http'. Webpack is throwing :

> "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'imports' in
>   '/home/pankaj/Openworld/play
>   Projects/admin-portal/app/frontend/node_modules/apollo-link-http/lib'
>   "

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: 'https://q80vw8qjp.lp.gql.zone/graphql'}),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `createHttpLink` instead or update `apollo-link-http` dependency.

```
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: createHttpLink({ uri: https://q80vw8qjp.lp.gql.zone/graphql" });
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Comment: I am able to guess where the problem is, but don't know the solution. Here is what is happening. HttpLink/createHttpLink is expecting a fetcher but When webpack is importing that file, it's not able to find the fetcher and hence throwing the error. I tried passing `node-fetch` as a parameter to `createHttpLink` but still, it's not working. @Dyo please help!

Comment: Fetch is a global function served by the browser runnning the app, webpack doesn't need it to build your app, i don't think this is the issue, you can try another version of webpack. Can i see your package.json and webpack config ?

Comment: The issue was with my webpack configuration. It's working now. Thanks!!

Comment: what did you change in your webpack configuration ?